# intellij idea unable to find a userdata.img file to copy into the avd folder

Tags: android-sdk, android, intellij-idea

При попытке запустить андроидовское виртуальное устройство выдает ошибку:

> intellij idea unable to find a
> userdata.img file to copy into the avd
> folder

С чем это связано? Откуда взять этот файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817044/how-to-create-a-avd-for-android-4-0)